# Org-roam raises "Selecting deleted buffer" error after formatting laptop

Tags: org-mode, org-roam

I recently formatted my laptop's hard drive and reinstalled my OS (Manjaro in dual boot with Windows 11). I restored my entire emacs configuration on Manjaro and everything seems to work properly, except for `org-roam`. Every time I call the `org-roam-node-find` function, I got a message saying "Selecting deleted buffer". The same happens when I manually evaluate the `org-roam` `use-package` block in my init.el file. This is my org-roam config:

```
(use-package org-roam
      :ensure t
      :custom
      (org-roam-directory (file-truename "/mnt/Data/MEGA/Notes/Roam"))
      :bind (("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)
             ("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
             ("C-c n g" . org-roam-graph)
             ("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)
             ("C-c n c" . org-roam-capture)
             ;; Dailies
             ("C-c n j" . org-roam-dailies-capture-today))
      :config
      (org-roam-setup)
            (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}")
      ;; If using org-roam-protocol
      (require 'org-roam-protocol))
```

And this is the full log of the error I get when I evaluate that `use-package` block:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Selecting deleted buffer")
  #f(compiled-function (connection) "Return true if the end of the buffer has a properly-formatted prompt." #<bytecode 0x15715abaaa11>)(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc>)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (connection) "Return true if the end of the buffer has a properly-formatted prompt." #<bytecode 0x15715abaaa11>) #<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> nil)
  emacsql-waiting-p(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc>)
  #f(compiled-function (connection &optional timeout) "Block until CONNECTION is waiting for further input." #<bytecode 0x15715aba6d21>)(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc>)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (connection &optional timeout) "Block until CONNECTION is waiting for further input." #<bytecode 0x15715aba6d21>) #<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> nil)
  emacsql-wait(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc>)
  #f(compiled-function (#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> (:file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db"))
  apply(#f(compiled-function 
  #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15715aca7ee9>)(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> (:file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db"))
  apply(#f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15715aca7ee9>) #<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> (:file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db"))
  initialize-instance(#<emacsql-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-15715ac878bc> (:file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db"))
  #f(compiled-function (class &rest slots) "Default constructor for CLASS `eieio-default-superclass'.\nSLOTS are the initialization slots used by `initialize-instance'.\nThis static method is called when an object is constructed.\nIt allocates the vector used to represent an EIEIO object, and then\ncalls `initialize-instance' on that object." #<bytecode 0x1571591a5669>)(emacsql-sqlite-connection :file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db")
  apply(#f(compiled-function (class &rest slots) "Default constructor for CLASS `eieio-default-superclass'.\nSLOTS are the initialization slots used by `initialize-instance'.\nThis static method is called when an object is constructed.\nIt allocates the vector used to represent an EIEIO object, and then\ncalls `initialize-instance' on that object." #<bytecode 0x1571591a5669>) emacsql-sqlite-connection (:file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db"))
  make-instance(emacsql-sqlite-connection :file "~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db")
  emacsql-sqlite("~/.config/emacs/org-roam.db")
  org-roam-db()
  org-roam-db-sync()
  org-roam-db-autosync-mode(1)
  org-roam-setup()
  (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require 'org-roam-protocol) t)
  (condition-case err (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require 'org-roam-protocol) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :config err)))
  (lambda nil (condition-case err (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require 'org-roam-protocol) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :config err))))()
  eval-after-load(org-roam (lambda nil (condition-case err (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require 'org-roam-protocol) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :config err)))))
  (progn (let ((custom--inhibit-theme-enable nil)) (if (memq 'use-package custom-known-themes) nil (custom-declare-theme 'use-package 'use-package-theme nil) (enable-theme 'use-package) (setq custom-enabled-themes (remq 'use-package custom-enabled-themes))) (custom-theme-set-variables 'use-package '(org-roam-directory (file-truename "/mnt/Data/MEGA/Notes/Roam") nil nil "Customized with use-package org-roam"))) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-buffer-toggle) nil (autoload #'org-roam-buffer-toggle "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-find) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-find "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-graph) nil (autoload #'org-roam-graph "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-insert) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-insert "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-capture) nil (autoload #'org-roam-capture "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-dailies-capture-today) nil (autoload #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today "org-roam" nil t)) (eval-after-load 'org-roam #'(lambda nil (condition-case err (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require 'org-roam-protocol) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :config err))))) (progn (let* ((name "C-c n l") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-buffer-toggle (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-buffer-toggle)) (let* ((name "C-c n f") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-node-find (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-find)) (let* ((name "C-c n g") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-graph (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-graph)) (let* ((name "C-c n i") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-node-insert (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-insert)) (let* ((name "C-c n c") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-capture (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-capture)) (let* ((name "C-c n j") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if (and nil ...) (symbol-value nil) nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if (stringp name) name (key-description name)) (if (symbolp nil) nil 'nil))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today (if ... nil binding)))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today))))
  (condition-case err (progn (let ((custom--inhibit-theme-enable nil)) (if (memq 'use-package custom-known-themes) nil (custom-declare-theme 'use-package 'use-package-theme nil) (enable-theme 'use-package) (setq custom-enabled-themes (remq 'use-package custom-enabled-themes))) (custom-theme-set-variables 'use-package '(org-roam-directory (file-truename "/mnt/Data/MEGA/Notes/Roam") nil nil "Customized with use-package org-roam"))) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-buffer-toggle) nil (autoload #'org-roam-buffer-toggle "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-find) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-find "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-graph) nil (autoload #'org-roam-graph "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-insert) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-insert "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-capture) nil (autoload #'org-roam-capture "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-dailies-capture-today) nil (autoload #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today "org-roam" nil t)) (eval-after-load 'org-roam #'(lambda nil (condition-case err (progn (org-roam-setup) (setq org-roam-node-display-template "${title:*} ${tags:55}") (require ...) t) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :config err))))) (progn (let* ((name "C-c n l") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-buffer-toggle)) (let* ((name "C-c n f") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-find)) (let* ((name "C-c n g") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-graph)) (let* ((name "C-c n i") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-insert)) (let* ((name "C-c n c") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-capture)) (let* ((name "C-c n j") (key (if (vectorp name) name (read-kbd-macro name))) (kmap (or (if ... ... nil) global-map)) (kdesc (cons (if ... name ...) (if ... nil ...))) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry (assoc kdesc personal-keybindings)) (details (list ... ...))) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list 'personal-keybindings (cons kdesc details)))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today)))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :catch err)))
  (progn (use-package-ensure-elpa 'org-roam '(t) 'nil) (defvar use-package--warning40 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (let ((custom--inhibit-theme-enable nil)) (if (memq 'use-package custom-known-themes) nil (custom-declare-theme 'use-package 'use-package-theme nil) (enable-theme 'use-package) (setq custom-enabled-themes (remq 'use-package custom-enabled-themes))) (custom-theme-set-variables 'use-package '(org-roam-directory (file-truename "/mnt/Data/MEGA/Notes/Roam") nil nil "Customized with use-package org-roam"))) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-buffer-toggle) nil (autoload #'org-roam-buffer-toggle "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-find) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-find "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-graph) nil (autoload #'org-roam-graph "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-insert) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-insert "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-capture) nil (autoload #'org-roam-capture "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-dailies-capture-today) nil (autoload #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today "org-roam" nil t)) (eval-after-load 'org-roam #'(lambda nil (condition-case err (progn ... ... ... t) (... ...)))) (progn (let* ((name "C-c n l") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-buffer-toggle)) (let* ((name "C-c n f") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-find)) (let* ((name "C-c n g") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-graph)) (let* ((name "C-c n i") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-insert)) (let* ((name "C-c n c") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-capture)) (let* ((name "C-c n j") (key (if ... name ...)) (kmap (or ... global-map)) (kdesc (cons ... ...)) (binding (lookup-key kmap key))) (let ((entry ...) (details ...)) (if entry (setcdr entry details) (add-to-list ... ...))) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today)))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :catch err))))
  eval((progn (use-package-ensure-elpa 'org-roam '(t) 'nil) (defvar use-package--warning40 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg ...)) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (let ((custom--inhibit-theme-enable nil)) (if (memq 'use-package custom-known-themes) nil (custom-declare-theme 'use-package 'use-package-theme nil) (enable-theme 'use-package) (setq custom-enabled-themes (remq ... custom-enabled-themes))) (custom-theme-set-variables 'use-package '(org-roam-directory ... nil nil "Customized with use-package org-roam"))) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-buffer-toggle) nil (autoload #'org-roam-buffer-toggle "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-find) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-find "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-graph) nil (autoload #'org-roam-graph "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-node-insert) nil (autoload #'org-roam-node-insert "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-capture) nil (autoload #'org-roam-capture "org-roam" nil t)) (if (fboundp 'org-roam-dailies-capture-today) nil (autoload #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today "org-roam" nil t)) (eval-after-load 'org-roam #'(lambda nil (condition-case err ... ...))) (progn (let* ((name "C-c n l") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-buffer-toggle)) (let* ((name "C-c n f") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-find)) (let* ((name "C-c n g") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-graph)) (let* ((name "C-c n i") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-node-insert)) (let* ((name "C-c n c") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-capture)) (let* ((name "C-c n j") (key ...) (kmap ...) (kdesc ...) (binding ...)) (let (... ...) (if entry ... ...)) (define-key kmap key #'org-roam-dailies-capture-today)))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning40 :catch err)))) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

My elisp knowledge is very basic so I don't know how to interpret this output. I tried to run `org-roam-db-sync` but I get the same "Selecting deleted buffer" error. I deleted the org-roam folder and reinstalled it but it didn't help and I wasn't able to find anything helpful on internet. Any suggestion is really appreciated!

Comment: I can't tell where it's going off the rails, partly because of ignorance, partly because the code is compiled and partly because there is an `eieio` layer that inevitably tends to hide things. It seems to me that the problem is an emacsql problem, rather than an org-roam problem, so I would try to see if I could get the emacsql layer working first. But unfortunately I cannot tell you how to do that. Hopefully, somebody with experience could give you some debugging hints.

Comment: Yes emacsql was probably the first problem since at the begninning I realised I haven't installed it, but even after installing it I still get the error message...but if that is the issue maybe I might find something more useful on internet using emacsql as keyword, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same error using `org-roam` on a new computer and also trying to use `forge` / `ghub` gives the same error.

Comment: I have finally solved this thanks to the comment in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/s9d6x3/comment/i6txokb/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which suggested the need to recompile the code under `emacsql-sqlite-[INSTALLED_VERSION]/sqlite/` runnning `make` within the directory. For me I was told the binary was up-to-date so I deleted it and re-compiled, bingo everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking this in as a solution but as suggested in [this answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/s9d6x3/comment/i6txokb/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) if you recompile the `emacsql-sqlite` binary it might solve the problem (worked for me).

```
cd ~/.confg/emacs/elpa/emacsql-sqlite/sqlite
rm -f emacs-sqlite
make
```